# Laravel calling wrong method

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a form calling submitting by post, the route: resource supposed to call **update** but is calling **show**

my route

```
Route::group(
    ['namespace' => 'Member', 'prefix' => 'member', 'as' => 'member.', 'middleware' => ['role:employee']], function () {

    Route::get('dashboard', ['uses' => 'MemberDashboardController@index'])->name('dashboard');

    Route::resource('profile', 'MemberProfileController');
```

my view

```
{!! Form::open(['id'=>'updateProfile','class'=>'ajax-form','method'=>'PUT']) !!}
                        <div class="form-body">
```

javascript

```
<script>
    $('#save-form-2').click(function () {
        $.easyAjax({
            url: '{{route('member.profile.update', [$userDetail->id])}}',
            container: '#updateProfile',
            type: "POST",
            redirect: true,
            file: true,
            data: $('#updateProfile').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

I am getting

**(1/1) BadMethodCallException
Method [show] does not exist.**

Sorry for don't post the code before

Comment: Where is your code? What is your question?

Comment: code? honestly. *eye roll*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this in your form : `{{ method_field('PUT') }}`

eg :

```
<form>
..
{{ method_field('PUT') }}
..
</form>
```